# Delphi : How to set sound/image locations?

Tags: delphi

How do I effectively set sound/image locations for example :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); begin
begin
  PlaySound('C:\Users\username\Desktop\project\sfx\Sounds\ding.wav', 0, SND_ASYNC);
end;
```

To something like :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); begin
begin
  PlaySound('ding.wav', 0, SND_ASYNC);
end;
```

Everytime I move The folder that contains the the project the sounds seem to not work anymore because the directory changes.

Comment: You could even link the .wav files inside the executable as binary Resources. Then you would have less stuff to send around when you give your program to your friends to try out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set / state the locations relative to the project file. For example:

```
var lApplicationExecutablePath: String;
lApplicationExecutablePath := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0));
...
var lSoundFile: String;
lSoundFile := TPath.Combine(FolderName, 'sfx\ding.wav');
```

This way you will have all needed files side by side no matter where the application is installed.

Answer (score 1):

If you supply a relative path it is interpreted as relative to the process working directory. As a general rule, in a GUI application you should always supply absolute paths since the process working directory may be ill-defined.

You don't need to hard code the file name. If you know the name of the file, and the folder that it is in, then you can simply combine the name of file folder with the name of the file, and obtain the full path to the file. Pass that to `PlaySound`.

```
uses
  IOUtils;
....
PlaySound(PChar(TPath.Combine(FolderName, FileName)), 0, SND_ASYNC);
```